# Select options from JSON file

Tags: forms, 8

I have JSON file with some id and value, and this need to be populated in form as select list:

```
$form['select_item'] = [
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#options' => $list,
      '#title' => $this->t('Choose'),
      '#required' => TRUE,
    ];
```

What is the best way to approach this. Can I somehow convert this JSON in array or something and use it in options?

I would like to have this values form JSON in separate file and to use it from there.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal doesn't have a lot to help with this, it's really a general PHP task.

If you're determined to use the API for it, just load the file data in any way you like (`fopen`, `file_get_contents`, etc), and use [`Json::decode()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Serialization%21Json.php/function/Json%3A%3Adecode/8.2.x) to turn it into an array.